# Htmlagilitypack. Select div by class and position

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack

I need to get certain *div* by class name and position. I know that in order to get some tag by class i write:
*tag*[@class='class_name'].But there are 2 tags with same class name so i get both. Is it possible to get only the first one? Thanks!

Comment: Does the example in the [SelectNodes documentation](http://html-agility-pack.net/select-nodes) help? Or if you want to do it in the XPath query, something like `tag[@class='class_name'][1]` is worth a try.

Comment: I tried your example, didn't work. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several way, the most commons are:

First one:

```
var firstDiv= res.SelectSingleNode("//div[1]");
```

Second one:

```
 var firstDiv= res.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault();
```

Good Luck!